# How to add, save and loop over custom activity fields in buddypress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Please help, I am trying to add some custom fields to the activity stream in buddypress but got stuck...

The following code adds two fields successfully to the activity form:

```
//add fields to activity
function add_activity_extra_fields(){
  echo
  '<div id="activitty-form-extra-fields">
    <input type="url" data-clear-btn="false" name="activity-form-field-url" id="activity-form-field-url" value=""   placeholder="Insert link...">  
    <input type="date" name="activity-form-field-date" id="activity-form-field-date" value="" placeholder="Insert expiry.. ."/>
  </div>';
} add_action ( "bp_activity_post_form_options", 'add_activity_extra_fields' );
```

Then I can read from $_POST and save to a custom table, but it's not working:

```
//save fields from activity
function save_activity_extra_fields( $content ) {
  global $wpdb;
  
  //$act_id = $_POST['activity-form-field-date'];
  $usr_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $date = $_POST['activity-form-field-date'];
  $url = $_POST['activity-form-field-url'];

  $wpdb->insert(
    'jrh_bp_activity_extra',
    array( 'user_id' => $usr_id, 'date' => $date, 'url' => $url ),
    array( '%s' ),
  );

} add_action('bp_activity_posted_update', 'save_activity_extra_fields');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I add the fields to the activity form like so:**

```
function add_activity_extra_fields(){
  echo
  '<div id="activitty-form-extra-fields">
    <input type="url" data-clear-btn="false" name="activity-form-field-url" id="activity-form-field-url" value=""   placeholder="Inserisci link...">  
    <input type="date" name="activity-form-field-date" id="activity-form-field-date" value="" placeholder="Inserisci scadenza.. ."/>
  </div>';
} add_action ( "bp_activity_post_form_options", 'add_activity_extra_fields' );
```

**Then save to a custom table:**

```
function save_activity_extra_fields( $activity ) {
  global $wpdb;
  
  $activity_id = $activity -> id;
  $url = $_POST['activity-form-field-url'];
  $date = $_POST['activity-form-field-date'];
  
  $save = $wpdb->insert(
    'jrh_bp_activity_extra',
    array( 'activity_id' => $activity_id, 'date' => $date, 'url' => $url ),
    array( '%d', '%s', '%s' ),
  );

} add_action('bp_activity_after_save', 'save_activity_extra_fields');
```

**Finally retrieve with the following function...**

```
function read_activity_extra_fields() {
  global $activities_template;
  global $wpdb;
  
  $id = $activities_template->activity->id;  
  
  $url = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT url FROM `jrh_bp_activity_extra` WHERE activity_id = $id" );
  $date = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date FROM `jrh_bp_activity_extra` WHERE activity_id = $id" );
  
  $extra_fields = (object) array( 'url' => $url[0]->url, 'date' => $date[0]->date);
  
  return $extra_fields;
}
```

**Unfortunately I couldn't find a better way, so I just call it from my custom entry.php template**

```
<div class="activity-inner-wish-extra">
    <?php 
        $extra_fields = read_activity_extra_fields();

        if ( isset($extra_fields->url) ) :
            echo '<p class="wish-url">'; echo $extra_fields->url; echo '</p>';
        endif;
        
        if ( isset($extra_fields->date) ) :
            echo '<p class="wish-expiry">'; echo $extra_fields->date; echo '</p>';
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can anyone of you help me? 
The values dont seem to save in the database, I have tried saving it in the meta table as well as a custom table.
I even tried to make a table in the db manually but it still doesnt add the values in the table

Answer (score 1):

This hook `bp_activity_posted_update` is not the best approach. Use this hook instead: `bp_activity_after_save`

And you should store it in this table: `$wpdb->prefix . 'bp_activity_meta';` unless you really want to use a custom table.

And your  `$wpdb->insert` query is malformed. You should have a format for each value in your data. [See codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#insert-row).

Comment: Thank you very much! I've made it to a working solution, but I still feel there's a better way to do it. If you happen to have some time, drop me a line ;)

Comment: If you feel that the answer was useful, you can up-vote it without accepting it.

Comment: I would, but I haven't reached 15 rep yet so stack doesn't allow me to do it, sorry

Comment: You have now :)

Comment: Thanks again, you were very helpful ;)